# problem with asp.netregsql

Tags: asp.net

i use from asp.netregsql but when i want to login to site it has this error:

```
The 'System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider' requires a database schema compatible with schema version '1'.  However, the current database schema is not compatible with this version.  You may need to either install a compatible schema with aspnet_regsql.exe (available in the framework installation directory), or upgrade the provider to a newer version.
```

what is problem?
this is my web.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <clear/>
    <add name="LocalSQLServer" connectionString="Data Source=Mahdi-PC;Initial Catalog=Shop1;Integrated Security=True"/>
    <add name="CS" connectionString="Data Source=Mahdi-PC;Initial Catalog=Shop1;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="Data Source=Mahdi-PC;Initial Catalog=Shop1;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
   <allow roles="Admin" />
  </authorization>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
                <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/></assemblies></compilation>
        <authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
        </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>
        <profile>
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
            </providers>
        </profile>
        <roleManager enabled="true">
   <providers>
    <clear />
    <add connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"
     name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
    <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider"
     type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" />
   </providers>
  </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like perhaps you haven't set an application name.  See this blog post by scott guthrie for help.

[Always set the "applicationName" property](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/22/443634.aspx)